# Travelling out of France with a receipt for first residence permit

Tags: france, schengen-visas

As title explains, I am wondering if it is possible for someone to go out and back in to France with an expired long term visa and a receipt for a first residence permit. 
The visa is a scientist visa.

Comment: Are you asking what the rules are or whether you might get away with it in practice? What's your citizenship?

Comment: @Relaxed I was thinking about taking a brief holiday in my home country Tunisia, so if there's a remote chance i'll be denied re-entry which might really interfere with my work then it's not worth the risk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This receipt (*récépissé*) is [*not* a valid document](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48715/travelling-with-the-application-receipt-for-a-french-residence-permit) to reenter France. I am not sure what would happen in practice if you go to another Schengen country but, if you leave the Schengen area, you may legally be denied entry when coming back and forced to restart the whole process (visa application, etc.) from scratch from abroad.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you go out... If you go out to a country within Schengen area, then since borders control are pretty random, there is a good probability that you won't have any problem to come back. If this involves getting out of Schengen area and coming back into it, then it will probably be more complex as then the visa will be checked...