# Can I travel in the Schengen area with an expired visa that is currently being renewed?

Tags: schengen-visas, italian-residents

I'm a resident here in Italy, I had my carta identita. I'm planning to go to France end of the month this September the problem is I'm on renewal on Sept 9' and I'll wait about 2 months to get it. Is it possible that I can go to France without it or can I attach a form that I'm for renewal to present it to the inspector in the airport in France ?

Comment: It might depend on your exact status but typically if you have an expired residence permit together with some receipt showing you applied for a renewal, you should be OK. Also, you probably won't have to undergo a police check if you fly to France.

Comment: If it is Ryan Air, they will insist on seeing documents.

Answer (score 4):

"Is it possible that I can go to France without it or can I attach a form that I'm for renewal to **present it to the inspector in the airport in France** ?"

When going by plane, you will **not** see a border inspector in the first place. Flights between Italy and France are considered domestic flights, since the Schengen Area (of which both France and Italy are a part) is a single country for border purposes.

If you check in online for your flight **and** only have hand luggage, there is a good chance you won't have to show any ID when boarding your flight (they often only require the boarding pass at the gate for flights within Schengen)

Otherwise, simply present a valid passport when required. As stated by the [**European commission**](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2010:0554:FIN:EN:PDF), check-in staff should **not** check your legal status, only that you're the person on the ticket. However, Ryanair notoriously violates this, so avoid them.

However, according to [**IATA**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=fr&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=vs&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), strictly technically speaking you are **not** allowed to make this trip:

> Passengers with a residence permit issued by **France, French
>     Guiana, French West Indies and Reunion**.This does not apply to temporary permits
>      issued pending a first application for a residence permit.
>   **In cases where a residence permit has expired, the
>      passenger must have a receipt of application for a new
>   residence permit and their expired residence permit.**

and

> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Andorra, Monaco
>     or another Schengen Member State for a max.
>     stay of 90 days.

Note there's no mention of expired residence permits or renewal receipts being accepted for holders of non-French permits

In other words, according to this info, your trip would be allowed if you had a French residence permit, but not with an Italian one.

Again, however, when flying within Schengen airlines are **not** supposed to check your legal status, and you will **not** meet any immigration inspectors.

In short: **according to Timatic, technically you cannot do this trip, but in practice you can as long as you avoid Ryanair**

Comment: Not supposed to, but they still check. And as far as I know there's no penalty for violating that rule.

Comment: @JonathanReez Ryanair does, but not others (or do you have any other experience with a particular Airline?)

Comment: I do, in fact I've asked a question about it here recently: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82734/do-airlines-have-the-right-to-check-schengen-visas-on-intra-schengen-flights

Comment: @JonathanReez Alright. Smartwings doesn't fly between Italy and France, or I would have added it to the answer. However, I know from experience that airlines such as Air France, Alitalia and easyjet, as well as Lufthansa, Swiss, LOT, Germanwings (though these aren't relevant) and a bunch of others rarely check ID at the gate for intra-Schengen flights (except easyjet), and if they do, they only check that you're the person on the ticket (including easyjet)

Comment: I don't think your inference that Timatic shows travel with this receipt is not allowed is correct. The text quoted in your answer does not state anything about permits from other EU countries one way or the other. My guess is that it mentions French permits because that's what makes the most sense in this context but this is really about the fact that only a receipt for a renewal (as opposed to a first application) exempts the holder from the visa requirement.

Comment: The official stance of the French government is that you can enter the *whole Schengen area* (not only France) or travel in other Schengen countries with such a receipt for application for a renewal (see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48715/travelling-with-the-application-receipt-for-a-french-residence-permit). Here again, it's about *French* residence permits but it would be difficult to reconcile that with not recognising similar documents from other Schengen countries.

Comment: @Relaxed Then it wouldn't say "issued by France, French Guiana, French West Indies and Reunion" but "issued by an EEA member state". The IATA folks know they have to be exact about how they word it, to avoid misinterpretation by check-in clerks

Comment: @Crazydre Except that we know that passengers with such a residence permit (actually a permit from a Schengen member state, not EU or EEA) can definitely enter France. So the way this should be read is that all the information in this paragraph is about French residence permit holders, it does not say anything one way or the other about other residence permits.

Comment: Also generally speaking I am not particularly impressed by Timatic, I would not be surprised if they misinterpreted something or they are being conservative in their assessment. The official documentation I presented in my answer to the other question (service-public.fr and the French government submission to the Prado database), while it's not completely explicit about the issue at hand, carries more weight for me.

Comment: @Relaxed What Timatic says is that all Schengen residence permits are accepted in France (which is basic knowledge to us), however renewal receipts are only accepted for holders of French Permits. I edited my answer

Comment: @Crazydre No, that's not what it says. It says that "temporary permits" issued following a first application are not accepted in the case of French permits (and as an exception to that, that receipts for a renewal are, however, accepted). It says *nothing* about this with respect to other permits, not even that temporary permits or receipts for a first application are not accepted.

Comment: The point I was making is that we all know that residence permits from other Schengen countries are accepted (and they are listed elsewhere in the Timatic output) so what "issued by France […]" means is that the whole paragraph is about French permits and obviously not that Schengen permits are not accepted. Interpreting the lack of information regarding Italian permits *a contrario* is therefore very questionable, especially in light of the other evidence I presented.

Comment: @Relaxed "It says nothing about this with respect to other permits, not even that temporary permits or receipts for a first application are not accepted". No, not *explicitly*, but why would it first list French permits *with* the note about expired permits, and **then separately** list Permits of other Schengen states *without* that note?

Comment: @Crazydre That's what I explained before: because that's most relevant for French permits (and also possibly because they haven't received information about that or misinterpreted the information provided by the French government). But that's in any case very shaky basis to consider that it is unambiguously *not* allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50192/discussion-between-relaxed-and-crazydre).